# {error:{ }} is being returned in express js backend (mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I'm trying to POST Data to Mongo DB Using Express Js.

I'm new to express just learned for a backend server

This is my **app.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv/config")
const User = require("./model/user.js")

let app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send("On Home!")
});
app.post("/register", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const myUser = new User(req.body);
        await myUser.save();
        res.send(myUser);
    } catch (err){
        res.send({error : err});
    }
});
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI,(req,res) => {
    console.log("Connected to Database!")
});
app.listen("5000" , () =>{
    console.log("Listening on localhost 5000")
})
```

My **user.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const User = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
email:{
    type:String,
    required: true,
},
pass:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user",User)
```

My **Response** Is

[My Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Qoo.png)

(I'm Using Postman to test)

Thank You For Your Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use body-parser, add this to your code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```